# WoW API / Lua - Math.Random(#,#)

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

Always feel like I'm making something far more complicated than it has to be. I'm currently playing around with the WoW addon, Tongues, in hope of make a custom dialect filter - which is quite easy of course, very noob-friendly. At this point, there is one thing I want to accomplish-- something of which feels to have the implications far beyond this -- that is just novelty, but before I give up completely (lots of hours trying different things with no headway) I was hoping someone could come by, get a cheap laugh and perhaps help me fix this if they understand my point. And who knows, posting this new helpless questions might bump me up to being able to finally upvote!

```
Tongues.Affect["Drunk"] = {
    ["substitute"] = {
        [1] = merge({
            { ["([%a]+)(%A*)$"] = "%1 ...hic!"},
            Tongues.Affect["Slur"]["substitute"][1]
        });
    };
    ["frequency"]  = 100;
};
```

What this does is simply add on the "...hic!" to sendchatmessage(); I believe it is. The frequency part seems completely broken and only the GUI slider in the game matters for that. What I was hoping to accomplish was to repurpose this and make the "...hic!" an actual randomized word. Since the mod itself handles the chance that it happens, I figured all that is needed left is to replace the string with a function=X. It's, of course, intensely way over my head, but despite checking the Lua of several mods, nothing feels like "it will fit."

The best I could come up with,

```
Tongues.Affect["TESTAFFECT"] = {
    ["substitute"] = {
        [1] = merge({
            { ["([%a]+)(%A*)$"] = function(b)
            local rand = Math.Random(1,2)
                if (rand == 1) then
                    b = "test1"
                    return b
                elseif (rand == 2) then
                    b = "test2"
                    return b
                end
            end
```

Leaves a gloriously useless message in the error mod BugSack - of course my attempt is wrong, but there's no way to know how!

I'm assuming this is enough information - as I said, very user friendly mod without any need to understand how it really works (Although I'd love to ready study it after this "project")

Anyone? Regardless, thank you for your time in simply even reading this far.

Update: Downvotes, okay! That's cool too. A little unpredictable, but sure.  The error is as follows

```
15x Tongues\Core\dialects.lua:172: attempt to index field 'Affect' (a nil value)
Tongues\Core\dialects.lua:172: in main chunk

Locals:
```

175 in dialects.lua is

```
        Tongues.Affect["Wordcut"]["substitute"][1],
```

Which has nothing to do with what I'm trying to accomplish, and works just fine.

Comment: _"Leaves a gloriously useless message in the error mod BugSack"_ Mind telling us what the error _is_? Also unless WoW messes with the builtins, it should be `math.random` (Lua is case sensitive)

Comment: Updating main post with error.

Comment: I'm fairly new to asking for help in general, since I never have until this, so I'm not entirely sure how my question was unclear, useless or lazy - I spent all night trying different things, looking for examples, and reading about  things. I'm new to Lua, and I the places I've began learning it are so theoretic that I have trouble applying what I see - I learn from example at this stage. At what point is it right to ask? /  All things aside, thank you for the correction, Colonel - I saw the caps version used before, so I assumed it did the same thing.

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The error message means that `Tounges` doesn't have a field named `Affect`.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I don't mind reading it again. The error message is bogus and a product of the error I created elsewhere, but another stack (It was somehow difficult for me to see it all these weeks of learning Lua and WoW API) proved my redundant symbol usage was breaking the mod, as one would expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that my question was an inconvenience. I asked to the best of my ability and the best of my ability to articulate the question proved to be less then stellar. The example codes I had provided were the only way I could articulate showing what I was trying to do.

I was misinterpreting the error frame and discovered that behind the useless stack that calls an error where there is, in fact, none, is a stack that calls the error in syntax at the time that broke it.

I'm sharing my results, regardless if the community finds this useless. I learned a tremendous amount from this personally, which is the only incentive in that I asked for help.

```
Tongues.Affect["TEST"] = {
        ["substitute"] = {
            [1] = {
                ["([%a]+)"] = function(a)
                    return a
                end;
                ["(%A*)$"] = function(a,b)
                     local rand = math.random(1,2)
                      if (rand == 1) then
                      b = "test1"
                    return b
                    end;
                      if (rand == 2) then
                      b = "test2"
                    return b
                    end;                    
                end;
            };
        };
    };
```

Hope it helps someone out there - as expected, I made it more complicated than it had to be. Simply "jiggling" the symbols is all that was needed.